# Aws ec2 ssh connect to host connection time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having some trouble to ssh back into my instance.

my instance id is : i-02c249e510ef15ab9

but when I just tested, "Launch more like this", I could ssh into that instance, which is : i-0d211ab6555e0e68c (currently off)

I don't understand, I have my security group inbound ports of 22 to accept all traffic, please let me educate me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi have you try telnet? 

`telnet instance-public-ip 22`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launch-more-like-this.html):

> The Launch More Like This wizard option does not clone your selected instance; it only replicates some configuration details.

So if there is something wrong with the SSH configuration of your instance, still the new instance launched "like it" can work.